# How do I move a site to another server?

Tags: migrations, 5

I'm having troubles migrating a Drupal 5 site. I don't have direct access to the original site, but I've been given the Drupal source files and a dump of the database.

When I upload the database to my local server and alter the settings file to connect to the database I can access the first page, but nothing else (eg: nothing within the admin area). When I click on any other link I get a generic HTML file with just one string of text in it. I can't even tell how the file is being generated, it's the oddest thing.

I'm really thrown off because I move Drupal 6 sites all the time, and although I do run into all sorts of problems related to file paths, a few search/replace queries in the database seem to fix most of those problems

So I'm wondering **if there is something specific to Drupal 5 that I should be doing** (but that I'm not aware of). Perhaps the database is corrupt?

I'm at a loss here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just thought I'd give an update: this problem actually had to do with Clean URLs, once I migrated the site, I had to disable Clean URLs directly in the database since I couldn't access any of the sub-pages of the website so I couldn't get to the admin area, then I replaced the custom htaccess I got from the remote server with an htaccess from a fresh Drupal 5 installation, and that basically solved it! Wow, what a relief, thought I was going to go crazy trying to figure this one out!